# Laravel global scope with if check

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, scope

So I try to have something like a global scope on my model so that I don't have to go and think about some parameters every single time.

The thing is I currently have the following Scopes-class;

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class NeedsPaymentScope implements Scope
{

    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param Model $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if ($model->needs_payment) {
            $builder->where('is_paid', '=', true);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have it included in my model like so:

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new NeedsPaymentScope());
    }
```

Now, since in the Scope class, the variable `$model` is like always empty, I can't execute the if-check (which needs to be done!) How can I have this logic implemented to every `get()`, `find()`; `findOrFail()`, ... method?

Answer (score 0):

You can NEVER access `$model->needs_payment` because model is not prepared yet, in other words you are in the middle of writing the query statement you can't access the model that it's query has not yet been completed.

Comment: Okay, then how CAN I access that value? Or how should I achieve this?

Comment: What's the full query that you are trying to write?

Comment: So I want to achieve the thing that there is a check wether or not the fetched row in the `sub_challenge` table that the column `needs_payment` is true and if that is true, that the record only gets returned when the `is_paid` value is also true then.

Comment: So I'd need both records that have `needs_payment` false and the `needs_payment` true + `is_paid` true

Answer (score -2):

try view composer for globle scope of variable.

with the help of AppServiceProvider you can define a globle scope of variable.

```
public function boot(){
View::share('variable_name','your_variable_logic_code');
}
```

if you have so many lines of code or logic you can use callback function tooo.

now you can access variable everywhere without passing in blade.
no comapct no with(method) without return to a blade you can access in whole app.

i think its helpfull for you.

Comment: Besides for the performance issues with sharing a global variable to every single view which should be almost always avoided, you've completely missed the point of Robin's question. The reason you can't use a variable in a global scope is because there is no model results yet - so if you can't do the if statement it in the query (like as a where), then it needs to be scoped another way in the code maybe as a local scope on other relationships.